# How do I open the Git GUI from a command window?

Tags: git, windows-7, command-line, git-gui

How do I open the Git GUI from a command window?  I'm using Windows 7.  I've tried running this:

```
"C:\Apps\Git\libexec\git-core\git-gui"
```

but that's not a windows script.  When I right-click on a folder, I see an option that says, "Git GUI Here".  When I click on that, the Git GUI opens up.  I want to do the same thing from a command line.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Simply entering

```
git gui
```

works for me.

Comment: And to open a specific repository: `git gui --working-dir C:\Projects\WorldDomination`. Had to look it up in the registry since I didn’t find it in the documentation.

Comment: @Martin Thanks a ton! I wasn't finding any doc on how to open a working directory

Answer (score 10):

Looks like you installed Git in C:\Apps, so in your case the exact command will be:

```
"C:\Apps\Git\bin\wish.exe" "C:\Apps\Git\libexec\git-core\git-gui"
```

Generally, assuming installation in a default location, this is the call:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\wish.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\libexec\git-core\git-gui"
```

Note that this answer applies to those who selected to not include git in the PATH variable during the installation process (on the screen below). If you selected the second option, then the other answer on this page (to just run "git gui") is the easier way to get to the UI from the command line.

[image: Git PATH configuration]

With 64 bit Git installed in the default location on a 64 bit Windows 10 machine, you can use the following line:

```
start "" "C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin\wish.exe" "C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core\git-gui" "--working-dir" "<path to your Git working directory>"
```

If you want the Git Gui to run in the current directory, then you don't need the `"--working-dir" "<path to your Git working directory>"`.

However, using the above `mingw64\bin\wish.exe` line results in some issues if Git is configured to use SSH. To have it working properly, it is necessary to change directory to the desired working directory and `start` `git-gui.exe`:

```
cd <working directory>
start "" "C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git-gui.exe"
```

Answer (score 1):

There *is* an executable that opens UI, located by default here:

```
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git-gui.exe
```

and in your case, apparently, here:

```
C:\Apps\Git\cmd\git-gui.exe
```

The UI can also be invoked by running generic `git.exe` from `bin` or `cmd` subfolders with parameter `gui` and with additional parameters

```
git gui [<command>] [arguments]
```

[as described in the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gui/).